# C++ Set an object as default argument (which is a reference)

Tags: c++, function, reference

I have been looking for a reply for this a lot, but I cannot find nothing. My compiler doesn't give me any error or warning, but maybe there could be any danger into doing this:

```
class Dog
{
   Dog(): x(0) {}
   int x;
};
```

If I have a simple class, creating a function in another class like this:

```
class PetHouse
{
    void addDog(Dog& animal = Dog())
    {
       // Anything...
    }
};
```

Is the addDog() declaration right? I have an argument **which is a reference** and it's default value is a Dog() object, instead an existing object.

Is there any danger?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Is it in Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes, it is Visual Studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it isn't. It should not even compile, because non-const lvalue references do not bind to temporaries like `Dog()`.

As @StoryTeller hints, you are probably using MSVC without `/permissive-`.

Comment: Thanks I'm reading about /za and /permissive- flags. First time I hear about them in the 7 years I have been coding!

Comment: @JuanJuezSarmiento You are welcome! :) MSVC has never been a "proper" C++ compiler; although lately (2017 onward) is way, way better than previous releases in that regard. Hopefully they will finish their efforts in the upcoming 2019 compiler and finally provide a conformant C++ compiler.